# How do I stop Alexa from opening the microphone after processing a response?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

On Alexa devices with a screen, how do I prevent Alexa from opening the microphone with responses that don't require the user to answer immediately? Even when I provide no `outputSpeech` or `reprompt` in the response, it still opens the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

On devices with screens, you can omit the `shouldEndSession` from the response object and the skill will remain open and will not open the microphone.

Here's a link to the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object) where it describes this behavior.

> shouldEndSession: undefined - The session's behavior depends on the type of Echo device. If the device has a screen and the skill displays screen content, the session stays open for up to 30 more seconds, without opening the microphone to prompt the user for input. For details, see How devices with screens affect the skill session. If the user speaks and precedes their request with the wake word (such as "Alexa,") Alexa sends the request to the skill. Otherwise, Alexa ignores the user's speech. If an Alexa Gadgets event handler is active, the session continues to stay open until the skill calls CustomInterfaceController.StopEventHandler or the event handler expires.